# AngularJs multiple instances and nested controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I got confused a bit about whether can we create multiple instance of controller and that to in nested form for eg -

```
<div ng-controller="abc"> 
   <form ng-submit="call()">
       <input type=text ng-model="content"/>
   </form>
   <div ng-controller = "abc">
       <form ng-submit="call()">
            <input type=text ng-model="content"/>
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

i just want to know that if i use the same model with other instance of controller, so model value would be same or different. Similar to static variable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i just want to know that if i use the same model with other instance
>   of controller, so model value would be same or different. Similar to
>   static variable ?

All declarations of `ng-controller` create a new instance of the controller.  So, if you had two instances side by side, like this:

```
<div ng-controller="abc">
    <input type=text ng-model="content"/>
</div>
<div ng-controller="abc">
    <input type=text ng-model="content"/>
</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iKCgbk?p=preview)

then, all of the `$scope` properties of each would be completely independent.

When a `ng-controller` is nested, then its scope *inherits* the parent controller's scope.  So for this you'd expect that content refers to the same scope property:

```
<div ng-controller="abc">
    <input type=text ng-model="content"/>
    <div ng-controller="abc">
       <input type=text ng-model="content"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cy25Tp?p=preview)

However, since `content` is not defined directly in the controller something strange happens.  If you fill in the parent `input` first.  Both, inputs become bound to the same scope property.  However, if you fill in the child `input` first, they are independent!

This can be confusing until you understand that Angular is being *lazy* when it *creates* the property on the scope.  `content` is null at first on both scopes.  It is only when it has a value that it will inherit.

So, what do you do if you want to keep things separate?  Add an initial value to a `$scope` property *inside* the controller:

```
app.controller('abc', function($scope) {

     $scope.content = '';
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8mEl6?p=preview)

This way, each separate controller instance is initialized with its own `content` property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And how are the scope properties passed from the directive into a nested controller?